# How to copy csv file two column values into Table in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

I am new in sqlQuery so trying to creating a script. I have two table "FirstTable" and "secondTable". also having csv file.
I am trying to create a sql script so that csv data will be copy in firstTable using secondTable Reference.

Rightnow i am trying to copy two csv column (LAT_HOLE, LONG_HOLE ) into FirstColumn.
This is my FirstTable.

```
ID  COURSEID    HOLE    LAT_HOLE    LONG_HOLE
1   789           1     
2   789           2     
3   789           3      
4   789           4     
5   456           1     
6   456           2     
7   456           3     
8   456           4     
9   123           1
```

this is secondTable.

```
COUSRE_ID   NAME
789         WEST
456         zoo
```

this is csv file format.

```
NAME    LAT_HOLE        LONG_HOLE
zoo      38.7204292     -77.01072156
Potomac  38.66841893    -76.96873426
```

your help would be greatful for me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 Create a new table named new_table that has similar structure of csv

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'filepath.csv' INTO TABLE new_table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
```

2 update firsttable with this

```
update firsttable as f inner join
(
select t2.courseid,t1.lat_hole, t1.lot_hole from new_table as t1 
inner join secondtable as t2  on t1.name=t2.name
) as t3 on f.courseid=t2.courseid
set
f.lat_hole=t3.lat_hole,
f.lon_hole=t3.lon_hole
```